# Logical distance between two Xpaths in html tree structure

Tags: c#, html, xpath, tree, html-agility-pack

Lets consider that we have three Xpaths (three nodes in html tree as [agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) returns html):

```
1_/html/body/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]
2_/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]
3_/html/body/div[3]/span[1]/div[1]
```

my problem here is to know smallest distance between those nodes **(which is closer to number 2 is it 1 or 3 ?)**, for example i want to know that

```
       html
        |
        |
       body
   /     |      \      
 /       |        \
div[2] div[1]  div[3]
  |      |         |
span[1] div[1]   span[1]
  |       |        |
div[1] div[1]    div[1]
```

any suggestions?
I have written a code depends on string comparisons but it costs a lot and i don't know if it will generalize well !!
so any idea will be usefull

Comment: So, what would be the answer in your concrete example? That 1 and 3 are equally close to 2 since they all share the same path prefix `/html/body`? Or is --- in your definition --- actually either of them closer to 2?

Comment: in my definition 1 is closer to 2 from 3